# Is there any way to achieve authentication and authorization without implementing UserDetailsService interface in Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

Currently, I am creating one login module for the project. In this module authentication and authorization must be required.

I am implementing the UserDetailsService interface in service class
but I am not using this interface.

UserDetailsService is the interface of Spring Security.

Is there any way to achieve authentication and authorization without
implementing the UserDetailsService interface in Spring with Hibernate?

I am currently working on java spring-mvc and Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes

Write a class by extending `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`

and overide `retrieveUser` method there you can write your logic for authentication and authorization

```
@Override
protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username,final  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException
```

And inthe Spring security xml

```
<security:authentication-manager id="restAuthManager">
    <security:authentication-provider
        ref="restAuthProvider">

    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="restAuthProvider" class="com.MyExtendedClass"/>
```